# Querying through an Arraylist

Tags: java, collections, methods, arraylist

I am building a program to read a `.txt` file and extract the student data and store it in a collection. Then the user is supposed to be able to select several different queries. The query that I am asking for help with is to select all students graduating, for example, in 2014 and then print these results to the screen.

In short, how can I search throw the `Arraylist` stored in `ProcessRecords` class for students who graduate in, for example, 2014? I can't seem to return records for students graduating in a specific year for some reason.

Below is my code.

#### First Class: ProcessRecords (with main method)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

 public class ProcessRecords {

public static void AskUser()
throws Exception {
    Scanner preference = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Creating a new scanner will allow us to gather user input

    boolean flag=true; 
    //I will use this for my while loop
    while (flag) {
        System.out.println("What type of Search would you like to run?\n 1)Search for all students\n 2) Search for students graduating in a specific year\n 3)Search for students whose last name begins with a certain string\n");
        int searchType=preference.nextInt();
        //This variable will store what type of query the user would like to run

        switch(searchType) {
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Gathering Records for all students\n");
            //Call Query Method in the Query Class to return all students in the collection
            break;
            //Call Query Method in the Query Class to return all students in the colletion
            case 2: System.out.println("What graduation year would you like to search for? \n"); 
            String yearsearch=preference.next(); 
            query.getYear(Integer.parseInt(yearsearch));
            //getYear();
            break;
            //Call Query Method to return students who are graduating in the specified year
            //Pass the "yearsearch" variable to the Query class
            case 3:
            System.out.println("What string would you like to search for? \n");
            String lstsearch=preference.next();
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Please pick a number between 1 and 3") ;
            break;
            //Call Query Method in the Query Class to return students who have the string in their last name
            //Also I need to pass the "lstsearch" variable to the Query class to search through last names                

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
throws Exception
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));
    //This will import the file
    input.nextLine();
    //This will skip the headers in the file
    System.out.println("Processing file now...");
    //Let the user know that the file is being processed

    int id;
    String last;
    String first;
    int year;
    int i=1;
    // Declare variables that we will extract from the file

    //Now we will being processing the file with a while loop

    List<StudentRecord> studentRecords = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        id=input.nextInt();
        last=input.next();
        first=input.next();
        year=input.nextInt();
        StudentRecord record = new StudentRecord(id, last, first, year);
        studentRecords.add(record);
        System.out.println(id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year + "\n");

    }
    System.out.println(" You have successfully read and printed from the file!");
    for (StudentRecord s : studentRecords)
        System.out.println(s.toString());

    Query query = new Query(studentRecords);
  }
}
```

#### Second Class: StudentRecord

```
import java.util.*;
public class StudentRecord
{
private int id;
private String last;
private String first;
private int year;

public StudentRecord(int id, String last, String first, int year)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.last=last;
    this.first=first;
    this.year=year;
}

public String toString()
{
    return id + "  " + last + "  " + first + "  " + year;
} 

public int getYear()
{

    return year;
}
```

#### Third Class: Query

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Query
{
private List<StudentRecord> records;

public Query(List<StudentRecord> records) {
    this.records = records;
}

public void getYear(int yearSearch) {
    //I am trying to create a method to get students who are graduating in a specific year.
    // I want to call this method in the ProcessRecord SwitchCase Case #2
    int count = 0;

    for(StudentRecord record : records) {
        if(record.getYear() == yearSearch) {
           System.out.println(record.toString());
            count++;
        }
    }


}
}
```

#### Question

If you could help me figure out how to search through the `Arraylist` with the student records for students graduating in a specific year and then print the entire line to the screen that would be great! I am very new to programming so I appreciate all of the help you can provide me.

Comment: Well, what is going wrong now? Do you get errors?

Comment: Seems like it'll work if you instantiate `Query query = new Query();` and then call its function: `query.getYear(Integer.parseInt(yearSearch));`

Comment: So my problem right now is for the GetAll() method in the Query class, it is saying that it cannot find the variable "studentRecords". Also, when I compile and void the AskUser method in the ProcessRecords class, it doesn't print anything to the screen.

Comment: where would I instantiate it in the code? I apologize I am very new to coding.

Comment: It's no problem, we have all been new once. I don't understand completely why you want to start with such a program instead of something easier to start with, but that choice is up to you. `studentRecords` is never created. It's not a class nor an instance of a class. You want to take a `StudentRecord` out of a list, so my guess is you mean `records` instead of `studentRecords`.

Comment: When you call `AskUser`, probably by instantiating that class, you need a parameter. That is your query. `AskUser(Query query)` is what it says. That `query` is your instance of the class `Query`. Try this: `case 2:
            System.out.println("What graduation year would you like to search for? \n");
            String yearsearch=preference.next();
            query.getYear(Integer.parseInt(yearSearch));`

Comment: Where do you run `AskUser`? I can't find it... After the last line of your `Main` method, after you instantiate the `query` object, try this: `AskUser(query);`

Comment: The above stuff should solve a few problems for you. Try to understand what is going on exactly. If you try to learn something with this application, write a comment above every line, like `//This line now does this`. It can also help to create a drawing with circles containing the method names, and linking them with arrows. Write next to the arrows what line of code calls the other 'circles'. That'll make you understand how it works! I can't respond for an hour now but I'll check in. Good luck!

Comment: I updated my code above with your suggestions... I am still getting an error when I compile the ProcessRecords class, it is saying "cannot find symbol- variable Query". Thank you for your help, I am really enjoying learning more about java! =]

Comment: If you are sure it's `Query` with a capital that gives the error, you would have to check your imports. I don't know in which IDE you are programming, but you should be able to rightclick the code (which probably has red lining beneath it or something like that) and do something like 'Resolve'. You can also try to add in top of your `ProcessRecords` class: `import mapname.Query;`. You should do this when your `ProcessRecords` class is NOT in the same package as `Query` class is.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void getYear(int yearSearch) {
//I am trying to create a method to get students who are graduating in a specific year.
// I want to call this method in the ProcessRecord SwitchCase Case #2
int count = 0;

for(StudentRecord record : records) {
    if(record.getYear() == yearSearch) {
       System.out.println(record.getId()+" " + record.getFirst()+ " "+ record.getLast() + "+record.getYear());
        count++;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted the code into my IDE, and a few points came to my attention. I've started with the code as described in your question, so I might say some things I've already described in the comments.

First of all, make sure that the right classes are imported. If your 3 classes are all in the same package, an import isn't needed. Also make sure that your classes are in the correct package then. Just placing the file in the folder isn't enough, above your `import` statements, you need something like:

```
package querytestproject;

import java.io.File;
...
```

When this is done, all 3 classes can recognize the other 2 classes and do some stuff with it.

The first thing that happens next, is here:

```
case 2:
System.out.println("What graduation year would you like to search for? \n");
String yearsearch = preference.next();
query.getYear(Integer.parseInt(yearsearch)); // <------------
```

`query` isn't known yet. You haven't instantiated that yet. A `Query` is an object that can help you search through a list of Students. You will need to give a list of records to that Query-object to achieve that. You do so in the `main`-method. You correctly create a Query-object there. But there is a small problem here.

When you do `Query query = new Query(studentRecords);` in the main-method, you instantiate the query-object locally. That means you can only use the query-object within the method it was created, being `main`. So, if you run `AskUser`, `query` is unknown to that.

To solve this (to make `query` global, is a solution), instantiate `query` in the class, rather than in a method.

```
public class ProcessRecords  {

    Query query;

    public static void AskUser()
    ...
```

At the end of the method `main`, replace `Query query = new Query(studentRecords);` by:

```
query = new Query(studentRecords);
```

You'll see an error popping up, because you try to access a non-static object in a static method (`static main`).

The static main method means that all objects created out from this class has only one method main. And you can call main method without instantiating the class and directly invoke this method with the name of the class. All instance variables and methods of the class that are declared as static are global variables or global methods. And we can call them directly without creating an object from a class by putting it’s class name in front of a variable and a method name in between the dot operator.

Thus, we create the `query` object like so:

```
static Query query;
```

Running the file will show you that the file is correctly readed. But, after that, the program stops. When you walk through all the lines of code in `main`, you see no reference to `AskUser`. After you have set up everything in your `main` method, it's time to ask the user what he wants. In the `main` method:

```
...
query = new Query(studentRecords);
AskUser();
```

The rest of your code is correct. `query` is correctly loaded with the list of Students, read from the file. `query` contains all the Students. So, if you search for a year, it will search through the List of Students you've just loaded by calling `query.getYear(x)`.